# wpf modern-ui How can I choose a theme in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In codeplex's mui, the app.xaml goes like this

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/modernui.light.xaml"/>


            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

but how can I choose the `FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/modernui.light.xaml"` in replace of `FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/modernui.light.xaml"` in code behind every time I run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ModernUI source code comes with a sample application that shows you how to do exactly what you ask.

The library has an AppearanceManager class. Set the current instance ThemeSource property:

```
AppearanceManager.Current.ThemeSource = AppearanceManager.LightThemeSource;
```

Comment: I copied this in my app.xaml.cs but the .Current and .LightThemeSource is in red. I tried importing the using FirstFloor.ModernUI.Presentation; but still the same. I manually typed AppearanceManager. but no intellisense.